# get all the css stylesheets linked to a webpage

Tags: html, css, error-console

I'm doing some testing using Firefox's Error Console. I'm fixing the errors in the stylesheets and I want to list all HTML pages that are linked to the stylesheets for regression test purposes.

Does anyone know of a tool (dreamweaver, aptana, online, etc.) that has this type of feature? FF Error Console only gives me the stylesheet URL, not the URLs of the linked HTML pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:  If you have dreamweaver:

1. Open a page on your website
2. Use **Ctrl+F**
3. Search: **Entire Local Site**
4. Source code: `stylesheet_name.css`
5. Select **Find ALL**

dw will give you a report in the Results Panel.

Answer (score -1):

It's not exactly what you are searching for, but maybe you find it usefull:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/css-usage/